# Is it possible to change font color based on background slider image name using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the font color of the navigation based on the color of the background image which is an image slider.  I'm adding a class to the nav by looking at the end of the image name "dark.png" or "light.png" to change the font color but I don't know how to get it to change the font color every time the slider switches images.

If there is a simpler/better solution already out there please let me know.  Also I realize I'm mixing pure JavaScript and jQuery in my example so if anyone has a pure jQuery solution that would be awesome.

Here is my code for a very simplified version for troubleshooting.  I also did a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markpfaff/hjamrnu3/) example.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.dark {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

            //slideshow:
            $(function () {
                var slideshow = $('body');
                var backgrounds = [
                    'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk1-dark.png)', 
                  'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk2-light.png)'];
                var current = 0;

                function nextBackground() {

                    slideshow.css(
                        'background-image',
                    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

                    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
                }

                setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
                slideshow.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
            });

});

(function colorChange(){
    var b = $('body').css('background-image');
    if(b.match(/-dark.png\)$/)){
        $("nav").addClass("dark");
    }else if(b.match(/-light.png\)$/)){
        $("nav").removeClass("dark");
    }
})();
```

Comment: Yes its possible but which colour you want to change

Comment: does the colorchange() function need to be independent of the other function.?

Comment: The only thing wrong I can see is that you never call the `colorChange()` function. There are some more errors you created in your fiddle, but after correcting them and calling the function it works: https://jsfiddle.net/hjamrnu3/6/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That worked! thanks so much.  I knew it would be something basic like that.  I also managed to mix up two different versions of the code but it looks like you got it sorted.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many options and here is one of them. Keep array of the classes with relative index of backgrounds. There is no need of extra color change function.

```
$(function () {
    var slideshow = $('.body');
    var backgrounds = [
        'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk1-dark.png)', 
        'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk2-light.png)'];
    var colorsClasses = ['dark','light'];
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        slideshow.css(
            'background-image',
            backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
        );
        $("nav").attr("class",colorsClasses[current]);
        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    }

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    slideshow.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
    slideshow.css("color",color[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have updates you jsfiddle here is working link https://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/hjamrnu3/10/

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //slideshow:
    $(function () {
        var slideshow = $('.cb-slideshow');
        var backgrounds = [
            'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk1-dark.png)',
            'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk2-light.png)'];
        var colors = ["#ffffff", "#FF0000"];
        var current = 0;

        function nextBackground() {

            slideshow.css(
                'background-image',
            backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);
            slideshow.css("color", colors[current]);

            setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
        }

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
        slideshow.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, here are the list of changes:

- You can simply use setInterval instead of recursing setTimeout
- 'nav' selector wont work for class='nav'

https://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/hjamrnu3/11/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        var slideshow = $('#cb-slideshow');
        var backgrounds = [
            'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk1-dark.png)',
            'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk2-light.png)'];
        var current = 0;

        function nextBackground() {
            var b = backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length];
            slideshow.css(
                'background-image', b);

            if (b.match(/-light.png\)$/)) {
                $(".nav").addClass("light");
            } else if (b.match(/-dark.png\)$/)) {
                $(".nav").removeClass("light");
            }


        }

        setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this above code

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

            //slideshow:
            $(function () {
                var slideshow = $('.cb-slideshow');
                var backgrounds = [
                    'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk1-dark.png)', 
                  'url(http://markpfaff.com/bk2-light.png)'];
                var current = 0;

                function colorcode(){
                 var a = $('.cb-slideshow').attr('bg-img');


if (a.indexOf('-dark.png') > -1) {
 $("nav").addClass("dark");
}else if (a.indexOf('-light.png') > -1) {
  $("nav").removeClass("dark");
}

                    console.log(a,"test",a.indexOf('-dark.png'));
                }

                function nextBackground() {
var element=backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length];
                    slideshow.css(
                        'background-image',element).attr("bg-img",element);
colorcode();
                    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
                }

                setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
                slideshow.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
            });

});
```

[js Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/hjamrnu3/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 JS libraries that will help you do the trick:

1. [Background Check](https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check)
2. [Color Brightness](https://github.com/jamiebrittain/colourBrightness.js)